# How SMTP relay process and relay an email to multiple recipients on different domains?

Tags: smtp

Given an email transaction to multiple recipients on two different domains `bar1` and `bar2`:

- `RCPT TO:a@bar1.com`
- `RCPT TO:b@bar1.com`
- `RCPT TO:c@bar2.com`
- `RCPT TO:d@bar2.com`

This email is sent to a relay. I wonder how does it relay the email to the 4 recipients on 2 different domains.

- Does it groups the recipient `per domain` and initiates an email transaction per group ?
- Does it create a transaction per recipient ?

What is the most common behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the mailserver. Either is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Does it groups the recipient per domain and initiates an email transaction per group ?

This is the most common behavior. The exact behavior is implementation specific.

Comment: @Craig-Watson answers is different from yours. Have you more information to support your answer ?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot as I said in my reply on my own answer, technically both answers are correct. Theoretically it's possible but in practice an MTA is rarely that intelligent and will treat the messages as separate emails.

Comment: By chance, my sysadmin was up for a test. I have test with this relay chains  `postfix` =>  `exchange` => `ironport` => `internet`. An email with 4 recipients/2 domains leads to 2 transactions on Ironport, one per domain and whatever the recipient order. I'm not sure yet if it is Exchange or Ironport which split the email.

Comment: Contrary to Criag's experience, my experience is that modern MTA's will group messages by domain. Modern MTA's will also send multiple messages in the same connection. So if you and your co-worker both send an email to the same domain, both will be delivered in the same TCP connection.

Answer (score 2):

Upon receipt of an email with multiple `RCPT TO` addresses, an MTA will most likely break the message into separate emails, and will treat each as a new message.

For four different recipients, the relay will receive one and forwards four different emails. Grouping/batching is beyond the scope of a mail relay.

If you are *writing* an MTA, it is possible to introduced some grouping/batching of emails with the same domain (so emails 1+2 and 3+4), but in practice MTAs such as Postfix or Exim will not do this.

Comment: Your answer is different from the @longneck one. Does it apply to a specific MTA?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot the SMTP protocol does allow the same connection to be used for multiple messages, so theoretically it is _possible_. However most (if not all) MTAs will close the connection after each message, so in reality it won't be used like this.

Comment: Do you agree my question is not about grouping/batching different email but an email with multiple `RCPT TO` with different domain?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot Upon receipt of the email, the relay breaks the message up into four messages, and will treat them as individual messages.

Comment: Using this relays chain `postfix` =>  `exchange` => `ironport` => `internet` the email recipients are split by domain. It could be different with postfix at the end of the chain. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

SMTP protocol allows for multiple messages to be sent using the same SMTP connection. Each message can be sent using the well-known commands:

```
MAIL FROM: sender@domain1.com
RCPT TO: recipient@domain2.com
DATA
Message body goes here
.
```

You can keep the same connection open and re-issue these commands for another message.

How it is implemented may be a different story and there is no obligation to re-use the same connection.

Comment: My qestion is about a message with multiple `RCPT TO` with different domain. What is the relay behaviour?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot: Different domains most likely means different destinations and so different connections. Grouping messages per connection/transaction can be good when connection establishment/teardown is costly. Is this your case?